# How to analyse and find the performance issue from Jmeter load testing results?

Tags: jmeter

I have done load testing for 100 concurrent users for simple login scenario using Jmeter. But I am not in position to say where the issue exist from load testing results. What are the parameters do i consider in order to find out the performance issue from the results?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

In order to find a performance bottleneck triggered by a Jmeter test, you real need to monitor the target hosts themselves, looking at things like CPU usage, memory usage, heap space usage, etc.  In addition, you need to evaluate the behavior of specific services that were invoked by Jmeter requests.

In other words, Jmeter can help you to create a load/performance/stress test scenario that will encounter performance bottlenecks in your application, but the analysis of the sources of those bottlenecks is really best handled as a separate system and application monitoring activity while the Jmeter test(s) are running.